# Setting $_SESSION sub-variables

Tags: php

I want to be able to set some variables under an already existing `$_SESSION`, like in my example, `$_SESSION['uid']['id']` or `$_SESSION['uid']['name']`. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
 $_SESSION['uid'] = [
    'id' => (int) $_GET['id'], //Cast the id to int
    'name' =>urldecode($_GET['name']) //url decode the name
 ];
}
```

This however gives me a `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /test.php on line 5`. I have tried everyting but can't find a solution. What is the correct way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You, probably, has PHP version lower than 5.4

Comment: [**You already asked this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24058401/) and accepted an answer. So, what happened between then and now?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, lol, he asked this question because the answer he got in that question

Comment: @Fred-ii- I couldn't get the answer to work, so I've tried different combinations those didn't work either. I had the answer printed since it was probably correct, but just didn't work for me

Comment: It could be because of the PHP version you're using then. Has the other answer below worked? @user3541436

Comment: You cannot just stand on the people's help. If each answer you get you are unable to get work, then maybe you should go back learning before coding? Are you from those kind, help vampires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously of PHP 5.4 you can't use brackets: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Use array instead:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = array (
   'id' => (int) $_GET['id'], //Cast the id to int
   'name' =>urldecode($_GET['name']) //url decode the name
);
```

Comment: Actually you can in a higher PHP version you should mention that.